# How to convert non null object (time in hr,mins,secs) to float in a dataframe

Tags: python, string, pandas, datetime, object

I have a `dataframe` that contains `int64` and object `dtypes`.
I am trying to convert the columns with object `dtypes` into float but it gives popping up errors.

I have used `pd.to` numeric but it all the values in the column get converted to `NaN(i used errors= "coerce")` 
[image: Image Here]

```
pd.to_numeric(file['Flégère'], errors="coerce")
```

I expected the `dtype` of `float64`.

Answer (score 0):

Your dataframe contains a timestamp. Pandas to_numeric can only parse numbers. '18:13:30' is not a parseable number. You should be using pandas.to_datetime

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html